# dynamic radio button through php and ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax, radio-button

```
<?php
session_start();
include'session.php';
include'dbconnect.php';

//unset($_SESSION['creatureid']);
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

function char_options() {
$sql="select id,name,type,level from characters where act_id='$_SESSION[id]'";
$sql2=mysql_query($sql);
$s=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
while($s) {
        echo"<input type='radio' name='char_choice' value='".$s['id']."'>".$s['name']." ". $s['type']." ". $s['level']." ";
    }
}
 ?>


<div id="frm_character_select">
<form action="">
  <?php  char_options(); ?> 
</form> 
</div>
```

So I am trying to make dynamic radio buttons which show 1 button per character on an account. My problem is that everything below the calling of the function is not loading on the page, and the page seems to load forever. Any pointers on how to fix this?

P (ajax) : on button (btn_character_selection) click it shows the div (frm_character_select) which has the radio buttons and information. None of the ajax is working either after i added the radio buttons.

Comment: Try `while ($s = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))` and see if that gives you anything different. Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
$s=mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
while($s)
```

to

```
while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
```

Comment: friend is that good t use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: Awesome... Thanks. No idea why I didnt catch that one. Been looking at code for too long.

Comment: @YadavChetan It totally depends on you , how you want to fetch the result as associative array or as numeric array. `mysql_fetch_assoc ` gives array as associative and `mysql_fetch_array` gives both numeric and associative. In my opinion `mysql_fetch_array` will be better because it gives both.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i know that but in case of specific is that better to use assoc

Comment: @YogeshSuthar are participated in any chat? i have some queries want to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    echo"<input type='radio' name='char_choice' value='".$s['id']."'>".$s['name']." ". $s['type']." ". $s['level']." ";
}
```